# field validation with element-react and arrow functions fails when wrapped with UserContext.Consumer

Tags: reactjs, validation

Using element-react UI components, I've been struggling to solve an issue caused by wrapping a form in

<UserContext.Consumer>

</UserContext.Consumer>

I get the error message:

```
Error: Function components cannot have string refs. We recommend using useRef() instead.
```

The content of the class is a copy/paste from [here, under the heading of validation](https://elemefe.github.io/element-react/#/en-US/form). And this code works fine in my application if I don't use the UserContext piece.
UserContext is declared in App.js as

```
export const UserContext = React.createContext();
```

Can you tell me how to rewrite this so I can use UserContext and have the fields validate with element-react please.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { i18n, Dialog, Button, Notification, Radio, Layout, DatePicker, Form, 
Select,Input,TimePicker,Switch,Checkbox } from "element-react";
import { UserContext } from '../App';

class MyPetsPage extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

 this.state = {
   form: {
     name: '',
     region: '',
     date1: null,
     date2: null,
     delivery: false,
     type: [],
     resource: '',
     desc: ''
   },
   rules: {
     name: [
       { required: true, message: 'Please input Activity name', trigger: 'blur' }
     ],
     region: [
       { required: true, message: 'Please select Activity zone', trigger: 'change' }
     ],   
     date1: [
       { type: 'date', required: true, message: 'Please pick a date', trigger: 'change' }
     ],
     date2: [
       { type: 'date', required: true, message: 'Please pick a time', trigger: 'change' }
     ],
     type: [
       { type: 'array', required: true, message: 'Please select at least one activity type', trigger: 
     'change' }
     ],
     resource: [
       { required: true, message: 'Please select activity resource', trigger: 'change' }
     ],
     desc: [
       { required: true, message: 'Please input activity form', trigger: 'blur' }
     ]
   }
 };
}

handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   this.refs.form.validate((valid) => {
   if (valid) {
    alert('submit!');
   } else {
     console.log('error submit!!');
     return false;
   }
 });
}

handleReset(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
  this.refs.form.resetFields();
}

onChange(key, value) {
   this.setState({
   form: Object.assign({}, this.state.form, { [key]: value })
 });
}

render() {
   return (   <UserContext.Consumer>
 {({user}) => <>
  <Form ref="form" className="en-US" model={this.state.form} rules={this.state.rules} 
labelWidth="120">
  <Form.Item label="Activity name" prop="name">
    <Input value={this.state.form.name} onChange={this.onChange.bind(this, 'name')}></Input>
  </Form.Item>
  <Form.Item label="Activity zone" prop="region">
    <Select value={this.state.form.region} placeholder="Activity zone" onChange= 
{this.onChange.bind(this, 'region')}>
      <Select.Option label="Zone 1" value="shanghai"></Select.Option>
      <Select.Option label="Zone 2" value="beijing"></Select.Option>
    </Select>
  </Form.Item>
  <Form.Item label="Activity time" required={true}>
    <Layout.Col span="11">
      <Form.Item prop="date1" labelWidth="0px">
        <DatePicker
          value={this.state.form.date1}
          placeholder="Pick a date"
          onChange={this.onChange.bind(this, 'date1')}
        />
      </Form.Item>
    </Layout.Col>
    <Layout.Col className="line" span="2">-</Layout.Col>
    <Layout.Col span="11">
      <Form.Item prop="date2" labelWidth="0px">
        <TimePicker
          value={this.state.form.date2}
          selectableRange="18:30:00 - 20:30:00"
          placeholder="Pick a time"
          onChange={this.onChange.bind(this, 'date2')}
        />
      </Form.Item>
    </Layout.Col>
  </Form.Item>
  <Form.Item label="Instant delivery" prop="delivery">
    <Switch value={this.state.form.delivery} onChange={this.onChange.bind(this, 'delivery')}> 
 </Switch>
  </Form.Item>
  <Form.Item label="Activity type" prop="type">
    <Checkbox.Group value={this.state.form.type} onChange={this.onChange.bind(this, 'type')}>
      <Checkbox label="Online activities" name="type"></Checkbox>
      <Checkbox label="Promotion activities" name="type"></Checkbox>
      <Checkbox label="Offline activities" name="type"></Checkbox>
      <Checkbox label="Simple brand exposure" name="type"></Checkbox>
    </Checkbox.Group>
  </Form.Item>
  <Form.Item label="Resources" prop="resource">
    <Radio.Group value={this.state.form.resource} onChange={this.onChange.bind(this, 'resource')}>
      <Radio value="Sponsor"></Radio>
      <Radio value="Venue"></Radio>
    </Radio.Group>
  </Form.Item>
  <Form.Item label="Activity form" prop="desc">
    <Input type="textarea" value={this.state.form.desc} onChange={this.onChange.bind(this, 'desc')}> 
  </Input>
  </Form.Item>
  <Form.Item>
    <Button type="primary" onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>Create</Button>
    <Button onClick={this.handleReset.bind(this)}>Reset</Button>
  </Form.Item>
</Form>
</>} </UserContext.Consumer>
)
}
}
export default MyPetsPage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error message is telling you:

> Function components cannot have string refs

Since you've made a class-based component, you can use [`React.createRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs) to create your `ref`:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  // ...
  this.form = React.createRef();
}
```

Now instead of this:

```
<Form ref="form"> // ...
```

do this:

```
<Form ref={this.form}> // ...
```

Now you can call the `validate` function using your `form` ref like this:

```
this.form.current.validate(...)
```

---

Complete example:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { useState, useRef, useCallback } from "react";
import {
  i18n,
  Dialog,
  Button,
  Notification,
  Radio,
  Layout,
  DatePicker,
  Form,
  Select,
  Input,
  TimePicker,
  Switch,
  Checkbox,
} from "element-react";
import "element-theme-default";

const UserContext = React.createContext("user");

class MyPetsPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      form: {
        name: "",
        region: "",
        date1: null,
        date2: null,
        delivery: false,
        type: [],
        resource: "",
        desc: "",
      },
      rules: {
        name: [
          {
            required: true,
            message: "Please input Activity name",
            trigger: "blur",
          },
        ],
        region: [
          {
            required: true,
            message: "Please select Activity zone",
            trigger: "change",
          },
        ],
        date1: [
          {
            type: "date",
            required: true,
            message: "Please pick a date",
            trigger: "change",
          },
        ],
        date2: [
          {
            type: "date",
            required: true,
            message: "Please pick a time",
            trigger: "change",
          },
        ],
        type: [
          {
            type: "array",
            required: true,
            message: "Please select at least one activity type",
            trigger: "change",
          },
        ],
        resource: [
          {
            required: true,
            message: "Please select activity resource",
            trigger: "change",
          },
        ],
        desc: [
          {
            required: true,
            message: "Please input activity form",
            trigger: "blur",
          },
        ],
      },
    };
    this.form = React.createRef();
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.form.current.validate((valid) => {
      if (valid) {
        alert("submit!");
      } else {
        console.log("error submit!!");
        return false;
      }
    });
  }

  handleReset(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.form.current.resetFields();
  }

  onChange(key, value) {
    this.setState({
      form: Object.assign({}, this.state.form, { [key]: value }),
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <UserContext.Consumer>
        {(value) => (
          <>
            <Form
              ref={this.form}
              className="en-US"
              model={this.state.form}
              rules={this.state.rules}
              labelWidth="120"
            >
              <Form.Item label="Activity name" prop="name">
                <Input
                  value={this.state.form.name}
                  onChange={this.onChange.bind(this, "name")}
                ></Input>
              </Form.Item>
              <Form.Item label="Activity zone" prop="region">
                <Select
                  value={this.state.form.region}
                  placeholder="Activity zone"
                  onChange={this.onChange.bind(this, "region")}
                >
                  <Select.Option
                    label="Zone 1"
                    value="shanghai"
                  ></Select.Option>
                  <Select.Option label="Zone 2" value="beijing"></Select.Option>
                </Select>
              </Form.Item>
              <Form.Item label="Activity time" required={true}>
                <Layout.Col span="11">
                  <Form.Item prop="date1" labelWidth="0px">
                    <DatePicker
                      value={this.state.form.date1}
                      placeholder="Pick a date"
                      onChange={this.onChange.bind(this, "date1")}
                    />
                  </Form.Item>
                </Layout.Col>
                <Layout.Col className="line" span="2">
                  -
                </Layout.Col>
                <Layout.Col span="11">
                  <Form.Item prop="date2" labelWidth="0px">
                    <TimePicker
                      value={this.state.form.date2}
                      selectableRange="18:30:00 - 20:30:00"
                      placeholder="Pick a time"
                      onChange={this.onChange.bind(this, "date2")}
                    />
                  </Form.Item>
                </Layout.Col>
              </Form.Item>
              <Form.Item label="Instant delivery" prop="delivery">
                <Switch
                  value={this.state.form.delivery}
                  onChange={this.onChange.bind(this, "delivery")}
                ></Switch>
              </Form.Item>
              <Form.Item label="Activity type" prop="type">
                <Checkbox.Group
                  value={this.state.form.type}
                  onChange={this.onChange.bind(this, "type")}
                >
                  <Checkbox label="Online activities" name="type"></Checkbox>
                  <Checkbox label="Promotion activities" name="type"></Checkbox>
                  <Checkbox label="Offline activities" name="type"></Checkbox>
                  <Checkbox
                    label="Simple brand exposure"
                    name="type"
                  ></Checkbox>
                </Checkbox.Group>
              </Form.Item>
              <Form.Item label="Resources" prop="resource">
                <Radio.Group
                  value={this.state.form.resource}
                  onChange={this.onChange.bind(this, "resource")}
                >
                  <Radio value="Sponsor"></Radio>
                  <Radio value="Venue"></Radio>
                </Radio.Group>
              </Form.Item>
              <Form.Item label="Activity form" prop="desc">
                <Input
                  type="textarea"
                  value={this.state.form.desc}
                  onChange={this.onChange.bind(this, "desc")}
                ></Input>
              </Form.Item>
              <Form.Item>
                <Button type="primary" onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
                  Create
                </Button>
                <Button onClick={this.handleReset.bind(this)}>Reset</Button>
              </Form.Item>
            </Form>
          </>
        )}
      </UserContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <UserContext.Provider value="user">
        <MyPetsPage />
      </UserContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
};
```

At this point it will work, but you will still see errors in the console about string refs. This is because [`element-react` actually also uses `string-refs`](https://github.com/ElemeFE/element-react/blob/master/src/input/Input.jsx#L154).

Comment: Thanks Bas, much appreciated, I found a workaround but will go back to your solution.